# Lightning message service(Build a Bear-Tracking App with Lightning Web Components)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-message-service

When I am making a bear tracking app this problem arises in the last module.
Error - afterRender threw an error in 'c:bearMap' [lightning/messageService: The `scope` property is required. When you call `subscribe`, include the `scope` property and set the value to `APPLICATION_SCOPE`. Format the call to `subscribe` as `subscribe(<context>, <channel>, <listener>, { scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE })`. Import `APPLICATION_SCOPE` from `lightning/messageService`.]

[Bear tracking App](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/lwc-build-flexible-apps/inter-comp-events)

bearmap.js file-

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { subscribe, unsubscribe, APPLICATION_SCOPE, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
//import recordSelected from '@salesforce/messageChannel/Record_Selected__c';
import BEAR_LIST_UPDATE_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/BearListUpdate__c';
export default class BearMap extends LightningElement {
  mapMarkers = [];
  subscription = null;
  @wire(MessageContext)
  messageContext;
  connectedCallback() {
    // Subscribe to BearListUpdate__c message
    this.subscription = subscribe(
        this.messageContext,
        BEAR_LIST_UPDATE_MESSAGE,
        (message) => {
            this.handleBearListUpdate(message),
            { scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE }
        });
  }
  disconnectedCallback() {
    // Unsubscribe from BearListUpdate__c message
    unsubscribe(this.subscription);
    this.subscription = null;
  }
  handleBearListUpdate(message) {
    this.mapMarkers = message.bears.map(bear => {
      const Latitude = bear.Location__Latitude__s;
      const Longitude = bear.Location__Longitude__s;
      return {
        location: { Latitude, Longitude },
        title: bear.Name,
        description: `Coords: ${Latitude}, ${Longitude}`,
        icon: 'utility:animal_and_nature'
      };
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The error tells you the problem.

Comment: But I don't know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually made a pretty easy error. The `{}` surrounding the object that's meant to be a parameter placed it inside the function body of the arrow function:

```
(message) => {
        this.handleBearListUpdate(message),
        { scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE }
    }
```

What you meant is:

```
this.subscription = subscribe(
    this.messageContext,
    BEAR_LIST_UPDATE_MESSAGE,
    (message) => this.handleBearListUpdate(message),
    { scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE }
);
```

To understand what happened, read the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) documentation.

Comment: Yes it has resolved my problem. Thanks for the help.